# Are questions regarding HTML semantics on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

I've noticed a number of questions as of late regarding "what elements should I use to make this layout," usually about the new elements introduced by HTML5. Here are some examples:

- [What is the correct way to layout this page using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40404962/215552)
- [Semantics navigation NAV vs ASIDE [on hold]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40390390/215552) (thankfully closed as opinion-based)
- [“Broken” links inside a <template> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40342480/215552)
- [Submenu title, h1 or span/other [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40244504/215552)

That last on was closed as a duplicate of [Best practice for providing a caption, title or label for a list in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1141639/215552), which itself seems to be quite opinion based, and indeed the accepted answer provides several alternatives.

I realize that not all subjective questions are off-topic, but it seems in these cases, there is no way of providing an objective answer, beyond what is mentioned in the specifications themselves.

Quite a number of questions of this sort get closed as opinion-based, but just as many are not. I could use my daily allotment of close votes for several years trying to close these old questions, but I'd like to get the community's opinion on whether these types of questions are actually off-topic.

I realize the answer is likely "depends", but I think it would be a healthy discussion to have.

Comment: Out of all of the questions you linked to, [this is the only one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40342480/1079354) which isn't opinion-based and has concrete answers using both HTML5 and Mustache.  Otherwise, I'm reaching the same conclusion as you; it depends on context and there's no blanket approach to them.

Comment: *"I think it would be a healthy discussion"* Questions aren't mean for **discussions** so it would be too broad or opinion based unless it's **very specific**

Comment: @Paulie_D.... Sorry, what? Meta is different from Main. On Meta, questions can be used for discussions; hence the `discussion` tag. This isn't the first "Are questions about *subject* on-topic?" question to have been posed here, so I'm a bit baffled as to that response.

Comment: Sorry I thought you mean discussion as questions on the main site.

Answer (score 9):

> Are questions regarding HTML semantics on-topic?

Potentially, yes - just like any other question about specification interpretation. Of course, they also need to meet the usual criteria for being on-topic - like being sufficiently narrowly-scoped (otherwise, "Too Broad" applies) and objective (otherwise, "Primarily Opinion Based" applies). But there is plenty that is entirely objective to be said about HTML semantics, and it is of practical importance - using semantically correct markup helps future developers understand the intent of your HTML and may help users with CSS disabled or who are using screen-readers to understand your page.

> I realize that not all subjective questions are off-topic, but it seems in these cases, there is no way of providing an objective answer, beyond what is mentioned in the specifications themselves.

That *"beyond what is mentioned in the specifications themselves"* point seems like a hell of a qualifier to me! If a question asked whether some strange behaviour of GCC was correct, or what the correct behaviour of a C program was (perhaps one written in a way that subtly invokes undefined behaviour), would you argue that the question was opinion-based because there was no way of providing an objective answer "*beyond what is mentioned in the C standards*"? I presume not. It's the same here - the existence of a standard (well, actually, two of them) upon which to base an answer is what *makes* these questions objective.

As for your specific examples:

> https://stackoverflow.com/q/40404962/215552

Too broad and too subjective. There are many semantically-correct ways to lay out the asker's multi-featured page, and he hasn't narrowed down his question to the semantics of any particular element. Quite rightly closed; while there are objectively incorrect answers, there are too many perfectly correct answers, just as much as if he'd asked "what's the correct way to calculate the factorial of an integer", and we should treat the two questions the same way.

> [Semantics navigation NAV vs ASIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40390390/215552)

Perhaps not the most the most well-written question, but seems reasonable enough. Its core is *"Which is the semantically correct element for a site sidebar of links - a `nav` or an `aside`?"* The underlying assumption that exactly one of these two ways must be *the* correct way is flawed, but nonetheless it's a legit question, which isn't opinion-based; the specs lay out the semantics of these elements carefully enough that it can be objectively answered based upon spec. (I think the right answer is "either is fine", but I had to delve carefully into the W3C and WhatWG HTML specs to confirm that using `aside` in this way is semantically legal according to both; it's a non-trivial question.) Doesn't deserve closure, and deserves a better answer (with spec quotes) than either that is currently posted. I've voted to reopen, and may return to edit and answer if it finally gets reopened.

> ["Broken" links inside a <template> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40342480/broken-links-inside-a-template-tag)

A *little* broad and woolly - it's simultaneously asking a narrowly-specified question about whether having a broken link inside a `template` is legal, and a more opinion-based question about whether it's "better" (how? why?) to use a different approach. Nonetheless, I think that's still a narrow and objective enough question to be okay. Doesn't deserve closure.

> [Submenu title, h1 or span/other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244504/submenu-title-h1-or-span-other)

I'm not even sure I understand the question. The asker premises his question upon a site layout that includes both a "menu" and a "submenu", but shows us example HTML that includes only one menu, with a class on it indicating that it is a "submenu". Huh? I'd close this as Unclear if it weren't already closed as a dupe.

Comment: See, the problem is, and you've kind of said it yourself with "I think the right answer is", is that "either is fine" is your opinion of what the standards say. My take on the standards is `nav` is only correct if the links in it are the *primary* navigation links of the site. I happen to agree with "unor", that an `aside` should not be used for primary navigation, because without it, the site ceases to be usable. I don't think the comparison to C is really adequate because there's a difference between undefined behavior and "I use `aside`s for navigation because it's not the main content".

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I haven't actually looked into `nav` in any detail, so you may be right about there being nuances I don't know about there. If so, I don't think that makes the question subjective - it just makes the answer to it that I suggest here *wrong*. I'd still defend the question as on-topic in that case.

Comment: Don't get me wrong; you make some good points I'll be sure to think about.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is no issue of providing an objective answer since these questions about the correct semantic usage of HTML elements boil down to which uses of them are the most accessible for everyone. While people may have their own idea as to what the answer is, there will always be a most correct answer regarding HTML semantics and accessibility regardless of the answers that fail to take these things into account.

Yes, some questions can be too broad and are more akin to asking someone to do the work for you but that doesn't nullify the usefulness of questions about HTML semantics and accessibility to the front-end web development community.

To answer your question truthfully, these questions are not off-topic and are very important to those still learning HTML semantics and accessibility. Lackluster questions can appear in any category and have no bearing as to the validity of questions regarding HTML semantics.

Comment: A question's usefulness is not its sole bar to reach for it to be on topic. A question regarding which IDE is the best from JavaScript programming is useful, but still off topic. I don't believe that there is a "most correct answer" to, say, the question of whether navigation links should be in an unordered list or just simply a series of anchors. Accessibility-wise, there is little difference between how each anchor is accessed or delivered to a user -- in fact, it may be easier without the list (https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/ for more).

Comment: @Heretic Monkey: Yeah but Chris isn't saying that all HTML semantics questions are on-topic by virtue of being HTML semantics questions - she's saying, in agreement with your OP, that they aren't *off*-topic for it alone. Such a question could be off-topic for being unclear or broad, or it could be reasonably scoped and have a practical answer, which doesn't have to be a cut-and-dry "one is better than the other" - it could just as well be, like you said, there is little difference. But I do think there is a level of subjectivity to this for this reason and therefore it's not purely objective.

Comment: But I think I understand what Chris means by objective, because it's true that semantics and accessibility are grounded in and supported by facts. A specific fragment of HTML objectively "does not mean" something the author thinks it does. A specific feature can be objectively accessible to one group of people and inaccessible to another. That said I think questions about semantics and even accessibility lend themselves to the "good subjective" or "constructive subjective" paradigm, which, of course, is a whole other can of worms on Stack Overflow compared to other SE sites...